# ERROR in understanding bit-wise operations

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have unsigned int (32bits) and want to divided into group of 3 short of 12 bits each.
    However, I unable to extract the numbers correctly. 
    e.g. Let's say I have 32 bit unsigned int as follows :

```
1111 0000 1011 0000 1010 1001 1100 1101
```

then I want something like this :

```
S1 = 1111 0000 1011 
s2 = 0000 1010 1001 
s3 = 1100 1101
```

Program :

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main() {
            short s1,s2,s3 = 0
            unsigned int addr = 4194624;

            s1 = addr>>12;
            addr = addr>>12;
            printf("%d\n", s1);
            s2 = addr>>12;
            addr = addr>>12;
            printf("%d\n", s2);
            s3 = addr>>12;
            addr = addr>>12;
            printf("%d\n", s3);

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you are modifying the `addr` variable, you should copy it in a temporary and do operation on it

Comment: Um, 12 * 3 = 36 which is greater than 32. You can have two 12-bit numbers and an 8-bit number, but you can't fit no more.

Comment: The shorts have [at least 16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types), so unless you really want to use 3 shorts, you only need two.

Comment: @user3114046 How do I print it in binary ? can I ? I have started learning c language like one week back.

Comment: @7heo.tk  yeah it is but 0000 will be added into the end.

Comment: @user2737926 to print in binary, you need to do it yourself. You can use a function such as [this one](https://ghostbin.com/paste/8tarr).

Comment: 3*12 is 36 bits. How do you expect to extract that from 32 bits?

Comment: @jaket he did already answer that he will pad the data with 0.

Comment: What I mean is: is s3 supposed to be left justified so that it is actually `1100 1101 0000` or right justified so that it is `0000 1100 1101`?

Comment: Ah I missed that comment.

Comment: @jaket From the OP, I'd suspect it has to be left-padded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
// Just pick up the last 8 bits of addr and
// assign it to s3.
s3 = addr & 0xFF;

// Shift addr by 8 bits to the right, then pick up
// just the last 12 bits of the resulting number, and then
// assign it to s2.
s2 = (addr >> 8) & 0xFFF;

// Shift addr by 20 bits to the right and then assign
// the resulting number to s1.
s1 = (addr >> 20);
```

Comment: I think if you change it to `s3 = (addr & 0xff) << 4;` since the op wants s3 right padded with zeros.

Comment: @jaket I didn't get that impression. However, hopefully they have the necessary info to do that, if they want to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use such a function to extract bits:

```
short f( unsigned int number, int start, int end)
{
    unsigned int mask = (1 << (end - start)) - 1;
    return ( number >> start) & mask;
}
```

Then:

```
int main() {

    short s1,s2,s3 = 0;
    unsigned int addr = 4194624;

    s1 = f( addr, 20, 31);
    s2 = f( addr, 8, 19);
    s3 = f( addr, 0, 7);

    printf("%d\n", s1);
    printf("%d\n", s2);
    printf("%d\n", s3);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

4

1

64

http://ideone.com/Q5mV94

Answer (score 1):

*Copied from comments* - see you have a 32 bit number first what i did was i store that in another variable and then right shifted it by 20 bits so the new number with me is a 12 bit number and then the same operation of getting the desired number was done on the other two 12 bit chains

```
#includde<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned long a=4194624,e;
    int b,c,d;
    e=a;
    e=e>>20;
    b=e;
    e=a;
    e=e<<12;
    e=e>>20;
    c=e;
    e=a;
    e=e<<24;
    e=e>>24;
    d=e;
    printf(" %d %d %d ",b,c,d);
    getch(); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide commentary for your answer so that the OP and future visitors to SO know what you're attempting here - and why.

Comment: see you have a 32 bit number first what i did was i store that in another variable and then right shifted it by 20 bits so the new number with me is a 12 bit number and then the same operation of getting the desired number was done on the other two 12 bit chains